# Request for AspNetHostingPermission failed on EDM Load

Tags: c#, .net, security, entity-framework, permissions

I am using Entity Framework in an application i am working on, however when i try to launch it from another user's machine, while trying to load the EDM i get an Exception stating that the request for the AspNetHostingPermission has failed. The assemblies are located on a network share.

The assemblies are not signed and as far as i know, since 3.5 SP1, assemblies on network shares run under full trust. What is going wrong?

EDIT: It seems this is a general trust issue, considering that i also got an error about ReflectionPermission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a trust issue. [Other people](http://forums.iis.net/t/1154825.aspx) have reported the same error when running from a [network share](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/upload/system-web-aspnethostingpermission-exception.aspx).

Comment: Yes, i think so, too. But i thought that one of the changes of 3.5 SP1 was, that apps running from network shares are full trust? That's what confuses me.

Comment: I set the network share to full trust. i guess it's ok that way.